# Add image directories in to EXE file

Tags: java, exe, exe4j

I’m trying to make an EXE file from my Java application using the exe4j tool. I have successfully built the project JAR file as well as the `lib` directory. I have created the EXE and its working smoothly. I am creating barcodes & profile photos in my application. This is how I set my path

- Saving Image

  ```
   File outputfile = new File("./src/com/ntap/solution/jmsystem/profilePics/"     + formId + ".jpg");
          if (outputfile == null) {
              outputfile.createNewFile();
          }

          boolean write = ImageIO.write(icon, "jpg", outputfile);
  ```
- loading image...

  ```
   url = "/com/ntap/solution/jmsystem/profilePics/" + formID.getText() + ".jpg";
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(url));
  ```

But after converting to the EXE, the image file path doesn't load from where it should load. error appears `File Could not found`

This process works perfectly with the JAR and also the Project. Are there any concepts I should know before settings paths like this that could be a problem in the exe?

Should I save the images on external location? like `C:/documents/..` How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Our community expects you to try to use proper formatting and spelling. If you haven't, go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Your `url` starts with a slash, indicating a full path; unless your jar file contains the full path to the image that way, the runtime isn't going to find the image there. Make a relative path to your image; the standard way is to put the image either in the directory with the class that loads it, or in a subdirectory of that named "images". In the latter case the URL to load the image would be "images/" + blahblah + ".jpg", in the former just leave off the "images/".

Comment: You can't save images to src, it doesn't exist at runtime. If the files are stored in the src directory, then building the project into a jar should include the images, depending on the build process

Comment: If recommend starting by using System.getProperty("user.home") and creating a sub directory for your program (convention would have you put it in the AppData directory)

Comment: @arcy Thank you very much for your knowledge and the suggestions!!

Comment: @madProgrammer yes, now i have a clear idea thanks to all of your   comments